# NopCommerce: Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task

Tags: nopcommerce

We are having this strange error. When the keep alive task tries to run, it gives this error: **Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

But when i try to run keep alive manually on the browser via example.com/keepalive/index it runs perfectly.

Our task code:

```
string url = "https://www.example.com/keepalive/index";

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadString(url);
}
```

We are using NopCommerce 3.70. What are we missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this:

```
  Check your store Url from Admin -> Configuration -> Stores.
```

Edit your particular  store from list and check **Store URL** might be not same with your browser URL.

Due to this reason you get error like **Error while running the 'Keep alive' schedule task. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

So please enter correct store URL and restart application.

It will resolved your issue.